# How to make plot.data.frame with more than two columns work with par(mfrow)

Tags: r, plot

When I call `plot` on a data frame with two [numeric] columns and `par` set to give me two columns of plots, I get the expected behavior:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
d <- data.frame(x=0:5, z=0:5)
plot(d)
```

[image: plotting canvas with left half filled by plot]

But when I call `plot` with a data frame argument that has more than two columns, it seems to override my `par` settings for rows/columns. The plot fills the whole canvas regardless of my `par` settings.

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
d <- data.frame(x=0:5, y=5:0, z=0:5)
plot(d)
```

[image: plotting canvas with entire area filled by plot]

Is this the expected behavior? Is there any way to get two plots of the sort given in the second example side by side?

Answer (score 0):

When a data.frame contains more than 2 columns, `plot(d)` calls `pairs(d)` to produce a scatter-plot matrix (see R help - ?plot.data.frame and ?pairs for more information).
In your case if you would like to produce 2 plots z~x and y~x side by side you can do the following:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
d <- data.frame(x=0:5, y=5:0, z=0:5)
plot(d[,-3])  # plot y~x
plot(d[,-2])  # plot z~x
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want to produce two of the `pairs` style plots side by side?